# IF formula to calculate hourly costs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to set an `=IF` formula to show as follows:

- If cell `B6 = 0`, then result is `0`
- If `B6 = 1` or more, then result is `B6*2.5+2.5`.

This is to calculate hourly costs, first hour is £5.00, second and subsequent are £2.50 each.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using Excel, if so this can be done with a simple if/else statement:

```
=IF(B6=0,0,(B6*2.5+2.5))
```

This reads as, if `B6` is equal to 0, then the value is 0, else it is equal to `B6*2.5+2.5` (where `B6` is anything other than '0'). Testing with 1 returns 5, testing with 2 returns 7.50 etc.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be a simple answer, can you also tell me, If B6 = "0" then can I display a blank cell as opposed to result "0"

Comment: Accepted formating from Tiago thanks for that. Yes, you must use "" for a blank cell instead, so your formula will look as: =IF(B6=0,"",(B6*2.5+2.5))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=(B6 + (B6 <> 0))*2.5`

```
=B6*2.5 + (B6 <> 0)*2.5
```

Boolean values like `B6 <> 0` or `B6 > 0` will be converted to 1 if true and 0 if false

Alternatively just use

```
=B6*2.5 + IF(B6 > 0, 2.5, 0)
```

Comment: Clever way of not using `=IF()`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without IF:

`=B6*2.5 + SIGN(B6)*2.5`